# Check Flask upload if user does not selected file

Tags: python, file-upload, flask

If user doesn't select a file in form (equals [PHP UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)
), `request.files['file']` also return a `FileStorage` object, I am using `request.files['file'].filename == ''` to check, any better way ? I have seen [Flask Doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) but can't find the answer.

`'file' in request.files` will not work on user doesn't select file, browser also will submit a 0 length and filename equals '' (empty string) part.

and how do I detect uploaded file was only partially uploaded error (equals PHP [UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now I am using

```
if request.files['file'].filename == '':
    return 'No selected file'
```

or using file length check

```
import os

file = request.files['file']
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
if file.tell() == 0:
    return 'No selected file'
```

Comment: Worked great for me, but I needed to add a `file.seek(0)` afterwards to be able to read the content of the file (at least when I simulated using `StringIO`)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
if not request.files.get('file', None):
    pass
```

If you want have most control over the files, you can use http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/

Comment: This doesn't work, `request.files.get('file', None)` will return a 0 length `FileStorage`

Comment: @SteelyWing, this should actually work and is a great way to accomplish it. The reason it works is that empty `FileStorage` objects evaluate `False`ly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import imghdr

def validate_image(stream):
    header = stream.read(512)
    stream.seek(0)
    format = imghdr.what(None, header)
    if not format:
        return None
    return '.'+format

class UploadFiles(Resource):
   def post(self):
      doc=request.files.get('image')
      if  validate_image(doc.stream):
         print('file validated')
```